# RedHat unable to install pip using get_pip.py

Tags: python, pip, redhat

I am trying to install pip using get_pip.py on redhat 7

Here is the result

```
sudo python get-pip.py --verbose
Collecting pip
  1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pip/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1e48bd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)': /simple/pip/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pip/'): Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1e48750>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)': /simple/pip/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (3): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pip/'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1e48250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)': /simple/pip/
```

Any ideas what the problem might be.

Comment: No proxy in the way? Any way to check an https website to see if you can get to it? Curl google homepage for example

Comment: The `connection timed out` errors look like you're having an internet problem. Try checking your connection.

Comment: Internet is working fine. I am behind a proxy server. I have exported http_proxy and https_proxy. wget and yum work just fine. However I just tried curl https://www.google.com and got a (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized error. It does work however if I use the --insecure option

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had to use --trusted-host pypi.python.org this stops pip from checking the validity of the ssl certificate for the specified site. In this case pypi.python.org